# "Where somebody/something at" ?

Tags: meaning, grammar, questions

I'm not a native English speaker, so I would like to have an explanation of that expression:
`"Where something/somebody at?"`

Examples :

> Where Brooklyn at ? (interlude in a Lonely Island album)
>
> Where you at ? (seen on a game server, instead of Where are you, I suppose)

Are not they supposed to say "`Where is/are ...`"?

Comment: Please **include the [research](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5039/50044)** you've done, or consider if your question suits our [ell.se] site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2573/50044) are off-topic.

Comment: The concept of "supposed to" doesn't really apply to language, or anyway not nearly as much as most people assume it does. The people saying "where ... at" are speaking their own dialect, and that is a normal and idiomatic construct in that dialect. It is not idiomatic in other dialects of English, for example Standard American English, and so to people expecting to hear that, this construct would make them take notice. Which has less to do with "correct usage" and more to do with "speak to your audience".

Comment: It's a colloquialism (https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/colloquialism), ie an example of informal speech.  While you could argue that they **should** say "Where is Brooklyn?", this is based on an assumption that everyone needs to talk formally.  In some contexts (eg business) this might be true but it's not generally true: in other words, informality such as this is permissible in informal contexts.

Comment: *Where you at* is sometimes more abstract, asking how far you have gone in an activity, how you feel about something, what's on your mind: *Where you at on dinner?* asks "Are you cooking already or can we go out?"

Comment: @YosefBaskin That particular construction would still only be used in certain situations/dialects; otherwise, it would be *Where **are you** on dinner?* The one place I do see this used a little more widely, with the more abstract meaning you describe, is in the phrase *meet people where they're at*, which is popular even in executive "inspiration-speak" and means something like "tailor your message to your audience".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nonstandard English, found in some dialects (particularly [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English)). The grammatical term you're looking for is "zero copula":

> The zero copula is far more common in some varieties of Caribbean creoles and African American Vernacular English, where phrases like "where you at?", and "who she?" can occur. As in Russian and Arabic, the copula can only be omitted in the present tense; the copula can only be omitted in African American Vernacular English where it can be contracted in Standard American English.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia: Zero Copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_copula#In_English)</sub>